# run a maven plugin goal with parameter in intiliji idea

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-plugin, liquibase, intellij-plugin

I'm using the liquibase maven plugin to run and rollback the migrations.

I'm running the rollback goal using the command line as follows:

```
mvn liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackCount=1
```

How to edit the configuration in intiliji idea to run the goal with the given parameter.

I'm using the intellij idea version : 2021.3.2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom Run Configuration for that, here is how to do it: [Run/Debug Configuration: Maven](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-maven.html)

You'll basically need to

- From the main menu, select Add Configuration.
- Name you configuration and provide the command and parameters.

Done! Now you just need to select it from the dropdown menu of run configurations and execute it.